# Java - find matching string from .text file

Tags: java, string, text, equals

I want to  find matching string from .text file.
but using this code I can only get the matching string of the first line of the text file. it does not run to the other lines of the text file

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

    System.out.println("Inside next line");
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    String[] tokenarray = line.split(":");

    if (tokenarray[0].equals(id)) {
        System.out.println("match found");
        System.out.println(tokenarray[0]);
        customer = new Customer(tokenarray[0], tokenarray[1],
                tokenarray[2], tokenarray[3], tokenarray[4],
                tokenarray[5], tokenarray[6], tokenarray[7],
                tokenarray[8]);
                break;
        }
}
```

This code works only when is input `id` as `tokenarray[0]` value of the first line of the document. I want to search whole text document. not only the first line.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like when you will remove the `break` it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String line = "hello:world:hello:up";
    String[] tokenarray = line.split(":");
    for (String s : tokenarray) {
        System.out.print((s.contains("hello") ? "match" : "no match"));
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
```

output:

> match, no match, match, no match,

Comment: whats the issue? Maybe he can re-iterate and add the matching Strings to a second list / array

Comment: Sure, sure. I was simply noting that OP example used a Scanner